# Is it possible to connect azure function that runs locally, to sql database running locally?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

Just started with Azure functions and I created one locally using visual studio. I saw how can I later connect it to Azure Sql, my question is can I also connect it locally to my sql db running on local sql server because I would just like to use it for testing purposes

Comment: Sure you can... You azure function will run locally so you can target you local SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a local SQL for local testing.

Please check in detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

The important part is in the local.settings.json configuration where you should put your local connection string here:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "<sqlclient-connection-string>"
  }
```